# TypeScript vs ES6 declaring variable types

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

In TypeScript I am used to declaring variable types using a syntax such as follows

```
function f(input: MyClassType)
```

However I have not seen such a syntax in ES6 or am I missing something here.  The same I would declare in ES6

```
function f(input)
```

My main point here is that the parameter type declaration is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However I have not seen such a syntax in ES6 or am I missing something here.

You are not missing something.

`ES6 !== TypeScript`

TypeScript is not the same thing as ES6 at all.  ES6 is not a typed language.  You don't declare a variable or a parameter with a type in Javascript.  So, if you somehow had a thought that ES6 was supposed to implement all the syntax used in TypeScript, that's incorrect.

ES6 did implement the `class` syntax which is pretty similar to what TypeScript was using (but without the types).  But, that's just a similarity.  ES6 is not a typed language and does not have variables with type declarations.